# Sklearn Logistic Regression - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence :

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to train a logistic regression model in SKlearn with the following code:

```
preds = np.zeros((len(test), len(label_cols)))
for i, j in enumerate(label_cols):
    print('fit', j)
    model = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=4, dual=True)
    model.fit(train_x[5:10], list(train[j])[5:10])
    preds[:,i] = m.predict_proba(test_x)[:,1]
```

I have a muli-label classification problem and `train[j]` represents one class at a time to train an LR model for multiple labels.

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-4c73d23d3af1> in <module>()
      3     model = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=4, dual=True)
      4     model.fit(train_x[5:10], list(train[j])[5:10])
----> 5     preds[:,i] = m.predict_proba(test_x)[:,1]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in predict_proba(self, X)
   1334         calculate_ovr = self.coef_.shape[0] == 1 or self.multi_class == "ovr"
   1335         if calculate_ovr:
-> 1336             return super(LogisticRegression, self)._predict_proba_lr(X)
   1337         else:
   1338             return softmax(self.decision_function(X), copy=False)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _predict_proba_lr(self, X)
    336         multiclass is handled by normalizing that over all classes.
    337         """
--> 338         prob = self.decision_function(X)
    339         prob *= -1
    340         np.exp(prob, prob)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    298                                  "yet" % {'name': type(self).__name__})
    299 
--> 300         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    301 
    302         n_features = self.coef_.shape[1]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have read other answers around the same problem but couldn't debug  my problem. The dimensions of all instances of X are of 300 size:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x:len(x)!=300, train_x)))
>> True
```

and len of train_x (features) is equal to train (the labels):

```
len(train_x) == len(train)
>>True
```

I also tested if all the values in the train_x are float, which is also True:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: all(isinstance(n, float) for n in x), train_x))) == len(train_x)
>> True
```

Comment: it's not look like dimension problem, more like type problem. train_y is the same type as train_x, and btw you made train_x[5:10] but give the whole train_y.

Comment: what is `preds`, how and where is it defined?

Comment: I am using 5 sample to test both. Can you please point this inconsistency?

Comment: added definition of `preds`